# How to approach a delete function that deletes from a database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an MVC application that will Create, Delete, Update client information.  I have created a a database and my connection is successful.  I also have a function that will read from the database and also add to it.  I am currently working on my delete function.  I am not sure exactly how to approach this function.  I am aware of the SQL call that will delete the a specific row in my database.

For example
`DELETE FROM Table_1 WHERE ClientNumber = whatever`

From what I understand this will delete only the row that is explicitly mentioned in that Delete string.  However, how about if I delete client name "John" and later I also want to delete client name "Jim"? how can I make a function that can dynamically delete from the database depending on what the end user decides.  So Far this is what I got.

The parameter I am bringing in is an Object that consist of: " ClientName , CleintType, ClientNumber".

```
public void DeleteClient(ClientInfo client) {
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Table_1 WHERE ClientNumber = 'client' ")) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ClientNumber` property of your client object and use [`SqlParameter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx) to pass that to the query.

```
public void DeleteClient(ClientInfo client)
{
    var qry="DELETE FROM table_1 where ClientNumber=@clientNumber";
    using(var c=new SqlConnection("YourConnString"))
    {
      using (var command = new SqlCommand(qry))
      {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientNumber", client.ClientNumber);
        c.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Great Thank you for you help

Answer (score -1):

If u want to Delete based on Name then only your existing sqlcommand has to change. like

```
string name = "clientname";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Table_1 WHERE ClientName = '" + name +"' ");
```

Comment: Not using SQL Parameters is, in my opinion, harmful advice. That is why I gave you a -1. If you don't agree, run your code and delete someone named `'; drop table Table_1; --`

Comment: Shouldn't that be validated and stopped before you fire the sql? i would.

Comment: @Shyju While that comic is great and all for a actual explaination of why this is a bad thing see [this really really good answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/25710/2221) on our security sister site.

Comment: @Necrovore does your validation have absolutely no bugs or loopholes that would allow code injection to get through? To verify that you are going to need to spend a lot of time and resources on that... Or you could just use parameters and be done.